# Creating a temporary of decltype

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype, temporary-objects

I have an object of some type, for example, `std::vector<int> v;`
Now, say, I want to verify that `v` releases all its internal memory.
Prior to the C++11 `shrink_to_fit()` method, the recommended/guaranteed way to do this is to `swap()` with an empty `std::vector<>` of the same type.

However, I don't want to specify the type of the object. I can use `decltype` to specify the type, so I'd like to write something like this:

```
std::vector<int> v;
// use v....
v.swap(decltype(v)()); // Create a temporary of same type as v and swap with it.
                  ^^
```

However, the code above does not work. I cannot seem to create a temporary of type `decltype(v)` with an empty ctor (in this case).

Is there some other syntax for creating such a temporary?

Comment: The recommended way to do this is `shrink_to_fit`.

Comment: @chris: Argh! True. I forgot about this method. Thanks, I'll re-edit, but my question still holds.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is that `swap` takes an lvalue reference: You cannot pass a temporary to `swap`. Instead you should switch it around so that you call the temporary's `swap` member:

```
decltype(v)().swap(v);
```

Of course C++11 introduced the `shrink_to_fit()` member so that the swap trick is no longer necessary.

Comment: Sometimes I really think there should be an `lvalue_cast` to create lvalue from temporary (pretty trivial to define as template, but it can't be done with naked `static_cast`). It has all the necessary properties, the rule is just a safeguard against common mistake.

Answer (score 5):

You can't bind temporary *rvalue* to a non-const *lvalue* reference, and so you can't pass it as the argument to `swap`. However, you can call a member function on a temporary, so this will work:

```
decltype(v)().swap(v);
```

In C++11, it would be clearer to move from the temporary:

```
v = decltype(v)();
```

or use `shrink_to_fit`

```
v.clear();
v.shrink_to_fit();
```

(Note that, if you don't have C++11, then you don't have `decltype`, so the question is moot).

Answer (score 4):

You may do (C++11):

```
v.clear();
v.shrink_to_fit();
```

or :

```
{
    decltype(v) tmp;

    v.swap(tmp);
}
```

`vector::swap` takes argument by reference. So temporary cannot be used here.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, `decltype(v)()` *is* the valid syntax for creating an unnamed temporary.
The source of the error, as the other answers explain, was that `swap()` does not work with the temporary returned by `decltype(v)()`.